# Ion propulsion lifter

Tags: electricity, propulsion

Me and some teammates are trying to build an Ion propulsion based lifter for some kind a physics challenge:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzZy1Aqleno

Firstly, We don't have a power supply of 30kv so that we've tried to use 4kv with with much more current in order to get the same power according to `P=iV`. Unfortunately, it failed.

Do you have any idea for how we should make this thing work, and why it isn't working right now, though we are getting the same power in a different current.

In addition, I would like to ask if there is an easy way to get a supply of 30kv.

Thanks.

Comment: In terms of "an easy way to get a supply", try Ebay. They can have some cheaper scientific equipment.

Answer (score 1):

In standard conditions at atmospheric pressure, air serves as an excellent insulator, requiring the application of a significant voltage of 30 kV/cm before breaking down.

So if you use 4kev you have to have an airgap distance that is similarly reduced, i.e. 2/15 as big, looks like around/below the 2mm sort of size. With the unaltered air gap you should expect no current to flow, regardless of the current the power supply is capable of supplying.

(Alternatively you could run your existing device in a vacuum.)